# Laravel 4 not working

Tags: localhost, laravel, mamp, composer-php

I've installed Laravel 4 on my local webserver ( MAC OS X ) and tried it also with MAMP.

I've installed the newest version of PHP and Composer and finally Laravel 4. I did the extra package-install with 'composer install', everything ran fine but it still doesn't work in my browser.

When I go on localhost into the respective folder I see a list of the folder items but no html page is shown, not even a 404. So I don't think it's the routing.

What am I doing wrong?

I was successfully running Laravel 3 before.

Any help appreciated.

Roman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try 
   localhost/yourfolder/public

Comment: you are welcome. when you are going to move your site to the server remember to put files in public folder to public_html or www folder of your Host and other folders (bootstrap,vendor,..) one level up. and please mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAMP without having configured its settings, you should use `http://localhost:8888/`

Answer (score 0):

With most certainty your web server is not configured correctly. The document root for your Laravel installation must be pointed to the `public` folder.

Take a look at this github repository that contains web server configurations for Laravel for the most popular web servers: https://github.com/daylerees/laravel-website-configs